# Group of centered images, last row issue

Tags: css, centering

I am centering a group of images using:
DIV Containter: text-align: center;
DIV Image: display: inline-block. (No Float)

It works perfectly, but the very last row which is 1 or 2 pixel shifted on the right, not matter how many rows there are (different resolution).

I can't make it work. See pages:

https://www.trampolineandparts.co.uk

https://www.trampolineandparts.co.uk/replacement-parts

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Try adding `div.img:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
    margin-left: 0;
}` + `div.img:nth-of-type(4n) {
    margin-right: 0;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mary pointed out, it's the space between elements. You can just use `display: flex` on the parent instead, and that will maintain the layout and fix the spacing issue.

```
div.imgcnt {
    /* text-align: center; */ /* no longer need this */
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center; /* if you want the `.img` elements centered on the page */
}
```

Comment: @scatmax great, you're welcome :) Be sure to mark one of the answers as the solution (the checkmark by answers) once you feel this is resolved.

Comment: Done! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You have whitespace between your inline-block elements for sure. Check if this will kill the unwanted space:

```
<div class="inline-block"></div><div class="inline-block"></div><div class="inline-block"></div>
```

Comment: I already fixed it as per Michael Coker tip.
Thank you for replying :)

Comment: As Michael more or less replied to my answer – thanks for no props. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try not leaving any space between your `<div>` and it should fix your issue.

Comment: I checked even before posting, but there is no space between the <div>.
Thank you anyway for replying :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi i took look at the website and noticed the 1 / 2 px displacement. It comes because of the display:inline-block. I tried fixing it. I would use float:left on the images rather than using inline-block. Try changing your css files to this.

```
div.imgcnt {
text-align: center;
padding-left: 6%;
}

div.img {
margin-left: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 160px;
border: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Hello,
This is how it was originally, with float: left but I removed it because I needed all the images dynamically centered.
Thank you for answering :)